# What is the term for young adult male/female (aged 18 to 25)?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When writing a book and referring to a female and male aged 18–25, what term would be most appropriate? *Boy* and *girl* seem too young, whereas *man* and *woman* seem too old.

Example sentence:

> A boy/man emerged from the shadows.

Edit:
I think the word I am looking for is similar to 'guy' but less American and colloquial. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try *young adult*

Comment: See JAM's answer; "A _youth_ emerged from the shadows" seems more graceful than "A _young adult_ emerged from the shadows."

Answer (score 6):

I think the best you can do here is

> A **young couple** emerged from the shadows.

If you need to specify gender, I would use *young man* or *young woman* as appropriate. While I agree with [Charles](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102591/25030) that in spoken English *young man* is used more towards children, I would posit that this is the case only when addressing them directly. I could, for example, address a 15 year old boy as *young man*. It would make me sound professorial, but it would not be out of place.

However, if someone were to tell me they

> saw a young man entering the house

I would think of a young adult, not a child.

---

Update:

The closest to *guy* would be *youth* but it only applies to males when used to refer to individuals as opposed to groups. Better, but also exclusively male, is *lad* but that is also more British than American. *Kid* can be used, but is ambiguous. An older person can refer to young adults as *kids* but it usually means children. Finally, and probably best in your case, you can use *youngster(s)*. Once more, though, this is a term that is used by older people towards younger ones. It is more used for teenagers and young adults than for actual children but it also carries an implication that the person using the term is older than those she is describing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the question to be a little more specific as I have not quite found the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Charlotte I have updated my answer with a few more choices. I don't think you are going to find _exactly_ what you are looking for.

Comment: Following @Charlotte's edit, I was thinking of "lad" (and "lass"), especially since she wanted something "less American." BTW "youth" refers to females as well as males.

Comment: @JAM, yes _lad_ and _lass_ are good but neither can be applied to both sexes. _Youth_ can, but only when applied to groups, not individuals. _I saw a youth_ implies a young man. _The fickleness of youth_ will apply to young people of either sex.

Answer (score 4):

"Young man" and "young woman", if you want to call attention to their age.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the question to be a little more specific as I have not quite found the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As [Jim said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102588/what-is-the-term-for-young-adult-male-female-aged-18-to-25#comment208651_102588), "young adult" is what I would *say*.  "Young woman"/"young man" somehow seems much younger in casual conversation.  It's what people would call me when I was a teenager or pre-teen.

But in literature, you can say "a twenty-something" or "a youngish man" or "someone who looks college-age" or any number of other descriptors.  What about their age is relevant to the work?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the question to be a little more specific as I have not quite found the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In work I do with this age group, they are always referred to as ***youth***.

EDIT:

After pondering your request for a word "similar to 'guy'", I have thought of **chap** and **fellow.** The disadvantage of both words is that they do not specifically refer to *youth.* Furthermore, they are in no way gender-neutral -- both refer to a man or a boy. However, to me at least, they carry a connotation of sprightliness that I for one would associate with youthfulness. To be clear, they *don't* mean that the person is 18 to 25 years old.

(I myself would still go for *youth*, though)

Comment: Always? Maybe in your line of work, but I don't think that's universal - it depends on the environment, I think. Some 23- or 24-year-olds might not like being identified as "youth." In some places, _youth_ is a label shed around 18 or 19; I've heard the term "college-aged" on occasion. Another option I've heard used to describe the 18-25 age group is "too young to rent a car," although that wouldn't work to solve the O.P.'s problem :^)

Comment: @J.R. You're right, it's not universal, but neither, as far as I can think, is any other term. I just wanted to add it to the discussion. I like "too young to rent a car" though... :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the question to be a little more specific as I have not quite found the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the setting or make reference to their ages earlier in the story, then readers will know the rough ages of the characters and you may not need to say 'young adult' later on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the question to be a little more specific as I have not quite found the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*Stripling* is fit for this category.

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stripling?q=stripling)

> Definition of **stripling**
>
> a young man:
> *he’s a mere stripling*

Perfect example: the Army of Helaman, "coming from the mormon religion, out of the Book of Mormon" ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Helaman)).

[image: The Army of Helaman]

<sub>These “stripling warriors,” it seems, could have **ranged in age from approximately twenty** (going by the Mosaic rule) to approximately **twenty-two** (those who could have been around age seven when the oath was taken) in the twenty-sixth year of the judges.</sub>

<sub>Three years later, sixty more young men from the land of Jershon joined ranks with their comrades (see Alma 57:6), perhaps having recently qualified by age for military service. Thus, in the thirtieth year, when Helaman wrote his long epistle to Moroni (see Alma 56:1), it seems possible that his youngest soldiers perhaps were **age twenty-one**, and his eldest, **twenty-six**.</sub>

---

<sub>Reference:

Tvedtnes, John A. “What were the ages of Helaman’s ‘stripling warriors’?” *The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints*. Intellectual Reserve, Inc. September 1992. 3 February 2012. (https://www.lds.org/ensign/1992/09/i-have-a-question?lang=eng#footnote2-92909_000_010)</sub>

Comment: Nice one, +1. Archaic, but spot on.

Answer (score 0):

"Adolescent" might work, if you are avoiding colloquialisms. But in the case you describe, I would use "a young man," or "a youthful figure," if you're preserving ambiguity about the character's identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Bachelor** probably has too much baggage. Collectively **'chummery.'**

But there are a number of military titles which might fit. Corporal, Sergeant, Lieutenant. Or

**Ensign,**  (rank)    "is a junior rank of a commissioned officer in the armed forces of some countries, normally in the infantry or navy." Wikipedia.

> **Buck**  [.4. *archaic* A fashionable and spirited young man: 'the dashing young  buck, driving his own equipage.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/buck) ' Oxford on line.

Apart from Regency Bucks, it describes an age related status in history, anthropology of Shaka Zulu, and Angami Nagas.

Comment: This answer is directed towards the specific case of @jFields99

Answer (score -3):

The term is *Millennials*, used in advertising a lot.

Comment: This might apply now. But you should note that this refers to a specific generation that will not always be this age. Eventually, the "Millennials" will be middle-aged. This suggestion also sounds pretty silly in the example sentence: "A Millennial emerged from the shadows."